# Creating key-value pairs from SQL result that have duplicate data

Tags: c#, sql, keyvaluepair

My problem at the moment is I have results coming back from a SQL query that returns a result like this:

```
125 Month   10.00   Wholesale
125 Year    20.00   Wholesale
126 Month   20.00   Wholesale
126 Year    30.00   Wholesale
127 Month   40.00   Wholesale
127 Year    50.00   Wholesale
```

where integer column is the ID of the column.
when the data gets returned to the C# calling code, it is placed into an object followering this structure:

PuctName;
            }

I am just having issues with how to create the terms without causing an endless amount of loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Linq and `GroupBy`:

```cs
List<ProductPricingGetDataItem> grouped = productInformationItems.GroupBy(
                                        p => p.ProductID,
                                        (key, g) => new ProductPricingGetDataItem() { ProductID = key, Terms = g.Select(x => new Terms(x.BillingPeriodName, x.PriceAmount)).ToList() }).ToList();
```

In order for that code to work, you need to add a constructor to `Terms` :

```cs
public Terms(string term, decimal price)
{
    Term = term;
    Price = price;
}
```

Fiddle with working example : https://dotnetfiddle.net/EE2BpP

Answer (score 2):

you can use a [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8) that way you will have a key value pair. the key is `ProductID` and the value the list of `Terms`.

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<Terms>>();
foreach (ProductTermAndPricingDataItem item in productInformationItems)
{
            if(dictionary.ContainsKey(item.ProductID))
            {
                dictionary[item.ProductID].Add(new Terms { Term = item.BillingPeriodName, Price = item.PriceAmount});
            }
            else
            {
                dictionary.Add(item.ProductID, new List<Terms>() { new Terms() {Term = item.BillingPeriodName, Price = item.PriceAmount             } });
            }  
 }
```

Comment: This solution doesn't return `ProductPricingGetDataItem` like you requested

Answer (score 1):

For LINQ lovers:

```
//Your initial data list
var productInformationItems = new List<ProductTermAndPricingDataItem>();
var productPricingGetDataItems = productInformationItems.ToLookup(item => item.ProductID)
                                                        .Select(grouping => new ProductPricingGetDataItem
                                                        {
                                                            ProductID = grouping.Key,
                                                            Terms = grouping.Select(item => new Terms
                                                            {
                                                                Price = item.PriceAmount,
                                                                Term = item.BillingPeriodName
                                                            }).ToList()
                                                        }).ToList();
```

In your exact case the result is :

[image]

Feel free to ask if something is not clear.